# DexException: Unexpected map value for 0x1

Tags: android

```
  Caused by com.android.dex.DexException: Unexpected map value for 0x1
  at com.android.dex.TableOfContents.readMap (TableOfContents.java:127)
  at com.android.dex.TableOfContents.readFrom (TableOfContents.java:70)
  ...
  at java.lang.Class.getDex (Class.java:450)
  at java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod.equalConstructorParameters (ArtMethod.java:112)
  ...
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance (Class.java:1679)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:6475)
```

We get this issue in Android 5.1 (SDK 22). What exactly does this ["Unexpected map value for"] mean? Is it a corrupt binary or missing some service on the device?

I can see the error itself is from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/eb5fee6/dex/src/main/java/com/android/dex/TableOfContents.java#127